# Achieve fullpage js effect on one section only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I've looked at all the demos and searched online but couldn't find the answer to it.

On this example link, it's a full page with the scrolling effect : http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html

How can I achieve this slides with the scroll effect in one section on my page? I tried using the options:

```
       fitToSection:false
       autoScrolling:false
```

With those options it works as only one section but the effect of the scrolling is gone.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just apply fullpage.js to a single section I'm afraid. The most you can do is [this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/oneSection.html) or something [like this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) with the internal scroll bar in the 2nd section.